# ArangoDB collection lock

Tags: arangodb

I am considering arangoDB for graph search.

I have two collection, one is people the other is movie and I made a graph between people and movie.

When I insert querying like below

```
FOR p IN people
  FOR m In movie
    FILTER p.movieName == m.title
    INSERT {_from:p._id, _to:m._id} IN peopleAndMovieRelation
```

When I querying above query, I cannot access peopleAndMovieRelation edge Collection. After querying is done, I can access that.

Does ArangoDB use collection lock when data is inserted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use ArangoDB with the MMFiles storage engine, writes block reads and locking is on collection level. Thus the edge collection can't be accessed while the query is executed and edges are written to `peopleAndMovieRelation`.

With the RocksDB storage engine however, document-level locks allow for concurrent writes. Writes do not block reads. Reads do not block writes.

https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/deploy/architecture/storage-engine/

Comment: Thanx I understand

Answer (score 0):

Here is additional explaination for storage engine.  [Comparing RocksDB and MMFiles Storage Engine](https://www.arangodb.com/why-arangodb/comparing-rocksdb-mmfiles-storage-engines/)

In shorten)

**MMFiles Storage Engine**
- ArangoDB Default Storage Engine in based Latest version(3.2)
- Collection level lock
- All indexes load main memory on startup(long start time if too many indexes but fastest access speed)

**RocksDB Storage Engine**
- Supported 3.2+
- Caching data in main memory, but load from disk if is needed
- All index is written on disk
- Fastest startup(No load indexes on startup), gradually increase performance